# Matlab function - How to get a "clear" function

Tags: matlab

I have a very long equation (Taylor polynomial) with coefficients `fa`, `fxa`, `fya` (and so on, see below). These are for approximating the value of the function `f` at the point `A = (a,b)`. The variables `a` and `b` are the two components of the point I want to develop the Taylor polynomial around.

The equation:

```
t = @(x,y) fa + fxa .* (x-a) + fya .* (y-b) + 1/2 .* fxxa.*(x-a).^2 + ...
           1/2 .* fxya .* (x-a).*(y-b) + fyya .* (y-b).^2 + ...
           1/6 .* fxxxa .* (x-a).^3 + 1/2 .* fxxya .* (x-a).^2.*(y-b) + ...
           1/2 .* fxyya .* (x-a).*(y-b).^2 + 1/6 .* fyyya .* (y-b).^3;
```

All of the variables named like `fxyya`, are integer values.

**I want to have a version of the fuction `t`, where my calculated coefficients are acutally "put in" and not only the variable names like `fxxy` and `fxya`.**

For instance, all 0 terms disappear and so on.

Ho do I get that?

---

For reference, all of the code:

```
    syms x y;
%f = input('Bitte geben Sie die zu evaluierende Funktion ein:','s');
f = 'exp(x^2+y^3)+x*y*(x+y)';
f = sym(f);
f = symfun(f, symvar(f, 2));
a = 0;
b = 0;

fx = diff(f,x);
fy = diff(f,y);
fxx = diff(fx,x);
fyy = diff(fy,y);
fxy = diff(fx,y);
fxxx = diff(fxx,x);
fxxy = diff(fxx,y);
fxyy = diff(fxy,y);
fyyy = diff(fyy,y);

fa = f(a,b);
fxa = fx(a,b);
fya = fy(a,b);
fxxa = fxx(a,b);
fyya = fyy(a,b);
fxya = fxy(a,b);
fxxxa = fxxx(a,b);
fxxya = fxxy(a,b);
fxyya = fxyy(a,b);
fyyya = fyyy(a,b);
 t = @(x,y) fa + fxa .* (x-a) + fya .* (y-b) + 1/2 .* fxxa.*(x-a).^2 + 1/2 .* fxya .* (x-a).*(y-b) + fyya .* (y-b).^2 + 1/6 .* fxxxa .* (x-a).^3 + 1/2 .* fxxya .* (x-a).^2.*(y-b) + 1/2 .* fxyya .* (x-a).*(y-b).^2 + 1/6 .* fyyya .* (y-b).^3;
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking ! Can you clarify a bit?

Comment: Your question becomes obsolete if you answer it in the question!! If you are not happy with any provided answer, but have solved the question, then add your own answer. Otherwise accept one of the provided answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `subs(t)`, but below is a cleaner version of your code without the need for `subs`...

---

You state that the coefficients are integers, but your example code creates them as analytically differentiated `syms` variables! Here is an adaptation of your code, which doesn't require `subs` to be used.

```
% Set up symbolic x and y, and symbolic function f
syms x y;
f = symfun(exp(x^2+y^3)+x*y*(x+y), [x y]);
% Set up points a and b
a = 0; b = 0;
% Get derivative functions analytically (these need to be evaluated at some points x,y)
fx = diff(f,x);     fy = diff(f,y);
fxx = diff(fx,x);   fyy = diff(fy,y);    fxy = diff(fx,y);   
fxxx = diff(fxx,x); fxxy = diff(fxx,y);  fxyy = diff(fxy,y);
fyyy = diff(fyy,y);
% Define symbolic function t
t = symfun(f(a,b) + fx(a,b).*(x-a) + fy(a,b).*(y-b) + ...
    (1/2).*fxx(a,b).*(x-a).^2 + (1/2).*fxy(a,b).*(x-a).*(y-b) + fyy(a,b).*(y-b).^2 + ...
    (1/6).*fxxx(a,b).*(x-a).^3 + (1/2).*fxxy(a,b).*(y-b).*(x-a).^2 + ...
    (1/2).*fxyy(a,b).*(x-a).*(y-b).^2 + (1/6).*fyyy(a,b).*(y-b).^3, [x,y]);

t
% output: t(x, y) = x^2*y + x^2 + x*y^2 + y^3 + 1
```

Comment: If you clear your workspace (`clear`) and run the above code, it should give the output shown?

Comment: Yes with your code above, it prints the shown output... But not with mine.

Comment: I found a way to do it!

By calling subs(t), it did exactly the thing I wanted it to do

Comment: Yes, you can see I've created them as integers. You said that yours were, but in your code example they are not - I have adapted my answer to show you how to avoid using excessive variables and the `subs` function. Please mark this as accepted if it answers the question.